# Do I need to create a new HttpClient for subsequent requests to new BaseAddress?

Tags: c#, httpclient, httpclientfactory

Take for example the following, I use a single httpClient, assign the BaseAddress, and then pass it to the client that will ultimately use it:

```
    var httpClient = httpClientFactory.CreateClient("morningstar-api");

    httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://UniqueAddress_1");
    _mfEODListApi = new RestEase.RestClient(httpClient);

    httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://UniqueAddress_2");
    _MFListApi = new RestEase.RestClient(httpClient)();
```

Is it better to assign the different base address as specified above, or should I create a new httpClient for each and give each new httpClient its unique BaseAddress?

Following the pattern above, I subsequently caught an exception:

> Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.

But I don't know if this unfortunately meaningless message is due to the way I'm configuring the httpClient or something else totally unrelated.

I'd like to have a better idea of the best practice for creating httpClients for calls to different BaseAddresses.

Comment: I would use one HttpClient per application, though if you have a _small_ number of base URLs, it's not unreasonable to have one instance for each. The error message likely means you got an HTML-formatted error page back from an endpoint and you're attempting to parse it as JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your use case, the [MS Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-7.0) gives you some ideas for which pattern to use.

> There are several ways IHttpClientFactory can be used in an app:
>
> Basic usage
>
> Named clients
>
> Typed clients
>
> Generated clients
>
> The best approach depends upon the app's requirements.